# How to periodically trigger jenkins multibranch job via groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I would like to my multibranch pipeline to run every 40 minutes and I will like to configure the job to do so via groovy Its been difficult to do so. Below is my groovy code.

```
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.DefaultOrphanedItemStrategy
import com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.bitbucket.*
import jenkins.branch.*
import jenkins.plugins.git.*
import jenkins.scm.impl.trait.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.*
import jenkins.branch.NoTriggerBranchProperty
import jenkins.branch.NoTriggerMultiBranchQueueDecisionHandler.SuppressionStrategy
import jenkins.branch.DefaultBranchPropertyStrategy
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.*
import hudson.model.*
import hudson.triggers.*

def jobName = "PipelineBuild"
def bitbucketUrl = "https://bitbucket.com"
def credentialIdForBitbucket = "12346790"
def repositoryName = "ApplicationRepo"
def projectOwner = "Loop"
def cronExpression = "H/40 * * * *" // Every 40 minutes

def multibranch = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(jobName, WorkflowMultiBranchProject)
if (!multibranch) {
    multibranch = Jenkins.instance.createProject(WorkflowMultiBranchProject, jobName)
}

def branch = new BitbucketSCMSource(projectOwner, repositoryName)
branch.credentialsId = credentialIdForBitbucket
branch.serverUrl = bitbucketUrl
branch.traits = [
    new BranchDiscoveryTrait(3), // All branches
]

multibranch.getProjectFactory().setScriptPath("ServerApiJenkinsBuild")

branchsource = new BranchSource(branch)
multibranch.setSourcesList([branchsource])
multibranch.setDescription("")
multibranch.setDisplayName(jobName)
multibranch.setOrphanedItemStrategy(new DefaultOrphanedItemStrategy(true, "30", "30"))

def periodicTrigger = new TimerTrigger(cronExpression)
multibranch.addTrigger(periodicTrigger)

multibranch.save()
Jenkins.instance.reload()

Thread.start {
    sleep 3000 // 3 seconds
    multibranch.scheduleBuild()
}
```

The script ran successfully however, the trigger was not set. Here is a picture of the job configuration
[image]

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try using the `PeriodicFolderTrigger` class instead of the `TimerTrigger`.

If you don't know exactly which class to instantiate, you can modify your job manually and then look at the xml config by appending `/config.xml` to your URL.

This is how I found :

```
<triggers>
  <com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger plugin="cloudbees-folder@6.815.v0dd5a_cb_40e0e">
    <spec>H H/4 * * *</spec>
    <interval>86400000</interval>
  </com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.computed.PeriodicFolderTrigger>
</triggers>
```

But also, 2 more things

1. I would recommend looking into the JobDSL plugin to automate your job creation.
2. This trigger will launch the "Scan Multibranch Pipeline" job, not the job itself. If you want to have the job running on a trigger, I would suggest specifying the cron trigger in your Jenkinsfile : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#triggers

Have a nice day!